# how to pass an object from class to anthoer? - views from one class to another?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4, uinavigationbar

I want to pass a view which has been made in 1st view like over here

```
        if (self.bookDetailViewController == nil)
            {
        iPhoneStreamingPlayerViewController *aBookDetail = [[iPhoneStreamingPlayerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"iPhoneStreamingPlayerView" bundle:nil];
        self.bookDetailViewController = aBookDetail;
        NSLog(@"View initilaized");
        [aBookDetail release];


    }


    //call a method from another class like over here 
     [booksNavController1 nowPlayingView:bookDetailViewController];


     //in 2nd view controller 

    -(void)nowPlayingView:(iPhoneStreamingPlayerViewController *)NPView
   {

    nowPlayingSong = NPView;


    }


    -(void)getSng:(NSString *)sng
     {
     name = sng;

     }


    //ibacton for toolbar button 


    -(IBAction)nowPlaying
    { 


    Music_appAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        [delegate.booksNavController pushViewController:nowPlayingSong animated:YES];
    }
```

here is what is nsloged "Application tried to push a nil view controller on target .
Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't release aBookDetail. i.e. comment out this line:

```
    [aBookDetail release];
```

Try that and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to structure your programm differnetly. The reason why you get null is because your class executes before you print the output.

```
Parser *parserClass = [Parser new];
parserClass.array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"One",@"Two", nil];
NSLog(@"%@", parserClass.array);
```

Sorry but you have to structure your class differently.

Or you could use the `(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];` to allow sharing between the class and the AppDelegate and then subclass accordingly.